# SQL to select with multiple different WHEREs / transpose / pivot table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, transpose

This is for BigQuery SQL

I have some data like

| version | color |
| --- | --- |
| v1 | red |
| v2 | blue |

I want to get it into an output format like this:

| v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- |
| red | blue |

I guess this is a classic transpose but not sure the best way to do this. I tried a nested query:

```sql
select * from 
(select color from table where version = 'v1'),
(select color from table where version = 'v2')
```

(simplified query from my real column etc names!)

but that gives me multiple rows per item with different versions of v1

most of the examples I found seemed a lot more complex.
https://towardsdatascience.com/pivot-in-bigquery-4eefde28b3be

Appreciate some help in basic pivots or groupby or the best way to transpose?

---

UPDATE it almost works but fails cos of field names.

```
select *
from (
    select agent, text, expect
    from `my.data.runs`
)
pivot (
    min(expect) as expect,
    min(agent) as agent
    for agent in ("august-mr")
)
```

> Invalid field name "expect_august-mr".

if my agent was named 'august_mr' it works fine!
Is there anyway to try and escape or enable a dash in the values for the agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simple pivot as in below example

```
select *
from table
pivot (min(color) for version in ('v1', 'v2'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: thanks! that almost worked except my fields have dashes in the VALUES which breaks BQs way of using them as temp field names... (see above)

Comment: you can add aliases to such columns - for example `for agent in ("august-mr" as august_mr)`